# Get Eclipse WebSphere Runtime Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a Java Project with two ClassPath entries, the JDK 1.6 and a "WebSphere Application Server traditional V8.0" runtime library.

I need to read all the JAR from an Eclipse Plugin, I try with:

```
IJavaProject.getPackageFragmentRoots()
```

But this method only get me the JDK libraries, How I can obtain all the WebSphere jar libraries from the eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am reading the project from an Eclipse installation that has no "WhebSphere" runtime installed, so, Eclispe is not able to read the WhebSphere runtime libraries.

I have created a User Library with all the WebSphere Runtime Libraries and now I can read the project with no problem.